# Windows10: ubuntu bash shell + mintty: tmux copy selection

Tags: tmux, windows-subsystem-for-linux, mintty

I'm using tmux under WSL Ubuntu bash shell in Windows 10 with mintty terminal (https://github.com/mintty/wsltty).

In tmux:
`Ctrl+B`, then `Ctrl + Space` I can make a selection (shown on screenshot). **But I don't get how to copy it in a clipboard**. Any Ideas?

[image]

Btw if I use tmux in native WIndows Ubuntu bash terminal I can not get to make tmux even to start selection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that right sequence to copy to `tmux` buffer is:
<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>b</kbd>+<kbd>[</kbd> and only after that
<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd> by followed manipulation with arrow buttons to make selection.

When you finished selection, press <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>w</kbd> to copy to `tmux`'s buffer.
To paste - issue <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>b</kbd>+<kbd>]</kbd>

If you have multiple copies, you can choose which buffer do you want to paste by issue:
<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>b</kbd>+<kbd>=</kbd> then choose buffer you need and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>

Comment: Thanks very much your combinations are correct. The problem with minty ubuntu bash tty, is that it doeesn't copy to windows clipboard, so copied text could be used outside of the console. Don't you have any ideas for this issue?

Comment: tmux using its own independent copy-buffer that isn't shared with anybody and there is a good reason behind it. The simplest way to share content from ubuntu console it to paste buffer to some text file and open it in windows. Personally I dont like this pair of spy(windows & ubuntu) and install when need it a cygwin environment. When you are in cygwin shell, all you need to copy 2 buffer is to press shift and select with mouse content you want to copy to windows buffer.